# and this little boy hit

Tags: comprehension

Video: [Tension Escalates for Desperate Refugees Trying to Enter Hungary](http://news.yahoo.com/video/tension-escalates-desperate-refugees-trying-013302687.html) (at the 1-minute mark)

Transcript:

> Now, to a real flash point overseas tonight. We have been reporting on the refugees. The worst refugee crisis in Europe since World War II. And tonight families blocked at the border, riot police launching tear gas, water canons **and this little boy hit**, dropping to his knees after the tear gas. Countless children caught in the chaos.

I assume the way he's speaking is something akin to the headlinese writing style so often employed by newspapers where they get rid of unimportant words to make their headlines sound more dramatic. Is that correct? So, then that line should be understood as *and this little boy has been hit by the tear gas*. Correct? I'm just trying to figure out if I'm getting everything right here.

Comment: I would interpret this excerpt just as you suggest, and it is headline-style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, a lot of that news clip is narrated in that "headline" style of short sentences with missing words.

It is unclear what hit him because they mention both the water cannons (and he is wet) and the tear gas (and he is crying).  In all the chaos, they probably don't know.

> And this little boy, who was hit, is dropping to his knees after the tear gas.